# Referencing an object from its attribute

Tags: python, class, oop

I have a class to create a player:

```
class player:

# Method to create object (Constructor)
    def __init__(self, pl_id, alive = True, health = 100):

        self.pl_id = pl_id
        self.alive = alive
        self.health = health
```

I then have an external interface which provides a unique id. I create a player from this id

```
def create_player(myInterface):

    # Get user attributes
    user = myInterface.unique_user

    print('Hello {}'.format(user['name']))

    myPlayer = player(user['id'])
```

I need to be able to reference myPlayer by it's id for future functions from the interface e.g

```
def take_damage(myInterface):

    user = myInterface.unique_user

    damage = myInterface.damage
```

I will have multiple players in the game, I want to be able to do something like so:

```
    myPlayer.health = myPlayer.health - damage
```

However I can't see how I can reference which player should be receiving the function. Should I dynamically name myPlayer to contain the user_id. Would this be bad practice? Is this the right use of a class?

myInterface is actually from another package (python-telegram-bot) so editing myInterface could be a little tricky...

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    def take_damage(self, damage):
        self.health = max(self.health - damage, 0)
        if self.HP == 0:
            print("{} dies....".format(self.pl_id))
            raise Dead
```